# I uninstalled Ubuntu, but UEFI manager still shows two boot options. Is it ok to delete them?

Tags: boot, uefi, uninstall, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu some time ago, and it went bad. I then uninstalled it, and a few weeks later reinstalled it and it went fine. Later I uninstalled it also because of some problems, and after all of that I saw that I had still two Ubuntu boot options on my UEFI manager (image below).
Windows booting is functioning well.

Now I want to install the newest version of Ubuntu, but first I want to correct all things. So, what I would like to know is if it's ok to just select the Delete boot option for both of them.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In short: Yes.

To elaborate a bit: Those boot options are stored in your motherboard's NVRAM, and point to files on your hard disk that either no longer exist or that are non-functional if they still exist. Deleting those entries (using `efibootmgr` from a Linux live CD, `bcfg` from an EFI shell, or sometimes from the EFI setup utility's built-in user interface) will simply delete something non-functional. Be sure to delete the *correct* entries, though -- you don't want to accidentally delete your Windows boot loader entry!